# How to check a UDP address exists with PHP and fsockopen?

Tags: php, sockets

I am using `fsockopen` to get information from a UDP address, the only problem being that some of the UDP addresses may not still be active.

I create the socket by

```
$fp = fsockopen($tracker, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
```

If the address is valid everything works fine, but if the address is invalid it generates this  error

```
Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in
```

I tried doing this but it still generates the error,

```
if(!$fp = fsockopen($tracker, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1)) {
     // ERROR
} else {
     // CONTINUE
}
```

I can error suppress it and all is good but I do not like error suppressing in my code.

How can I make sure any given UDP address is still active with php?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if there is a PHP setting to disable socket/stream errors like you can do with libxml and cURL. Like you said, you can also use the nasty old hack `@fsockeopen(...)` to suppress them.

Comment: I would if I could like to use cURL but it does not support UDP, at least I don't know how to do it if it does!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of suppressing the error `@` which you could do, you could implement your own error handler. [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

```
<?php
//Simple Blank error handler
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {}

function checkUDP($host,$port=80){
    //look no suppression
    $fp = fsockopen("udp://".$host, $port, $errno, $errstr,1.0);
    if (!$fp) {
        return false;
    } else {
        fclose($fp);
        return true;
    }
}

$good = 'tracker.publicbt.com';
$bad = 'trjjacker.publicbt.com';

if(checkUDP($good)){
    echo $good.' Good';
}else{
    echo $good.' Bad';
}
echo '<br />';
if(checkUDP($bad)){
    echo $bad.' Good';
}else{
    echo $bad.' Bad';
}

//tracker.publicbt.com Good
//trjjacker.publicbt.com Bad
?>
```