# Drupal - Checking online/offline status of external server

Tags: php, html, database, drupal, drupal-7

Im trying to integrate a php script which would check every 30 seconds if the particular server is either offline or online and then appropriatley print the status on my Drupal 7.23 website.

I came up with the code below, however the php script is reporting that the server is offline all the time, even tho it is online. Im not sure what is the problem.

```
<div class="serverstatus">  
<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", 0);  //hide fsockopen/fopen warnings if file doesn't exist or couldn't connect
$g_Status = 0;

$g_Ip = "0.0.0.0";  //Server ip
$g_Port = "0000";   //Server Port

function IsOnline($ip, $port)
{
    $sock=@fsockopen($ip, $port, $errNo, $errStr, 3);//timeout set to 3 seconds
    if($sock)
    {
        fclose($sock);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function RefreshStatus()
{
    global $g_Ip, $g_Port;
    $status = IsOnline($g_Ip, $g_Port);
    //storing info about timestamp and server status
    $file = fopen("status.txt", "wb");
    $timestamp = time() + 30;   //it will refresh every 30 seconds - won't flood the server
    $cont = $timestamp .' '. $status;
    fwrite($file, $cont);
    fclose($file);
    return $status;
}

$file = fopen("status.txt", "r");
if(!$file)
{
    //file doesn't exist
    $g_Status = RefreshStatus();
}else
{
    $cont = fread($file, filesize("status.txt"));
    $data = explode(" ", $cont);    //$data[0] is our timestamp and $data[1] is our server status
    if($data[0] < time())
    {
        //refresh status
        $g_Status = RefreshStatus();
    }else
    {
        $g_Status = $data[1];
    }
}

//Display server status
if($g_Status)
{
    echo "Online";
}else
{
    echo "Offline";
}

?>
</div>
```

Im very grateful for all the answers! Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Instead of suppressing errors for `@fsockopen` why not remove the `@` and find the error?

Comment: @BenFortune I tried removing the @, however drupal isnt reporting any errors. It says the server is offline, even tho its not.

Comment: What kind of server is it?

Comment: @BenFortune It is a dedicated game server for Lineage 2 if it makes any difference?

Comment: Oh my, sorry. After removing the @ from fsockopen drupal sometimes report the following error: 
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to :0 (Failed to parse address "") in IsOnline() (line 101 of C:\wamp\www\lineage2\sites\all\themes\...\templates\page.tpl.php).

Comment: Hm, try `$sock=fsockopen("udp://".$ip, $port, $errNo, $errStr, 3);` since most game servers use the UDP protocol.

Comment: @BenFortune I tried ur code line but it didnt help. Its still offline and reporting the same error that its unable to connect, thanks for ur effort.

Comment: Can the problem be in drupal not fully recognising the php? Im not really familiar with Drupal API and my post got closed on drupalanswers regarding this topic.

Comment: Drupal 7 (current) drupal_http_request() does not support `udp`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837999/784877

Comment: @AyeshK I am sorry but i dont understand what do you mean as im not much familiar with drupal api. Is the above php code unappropriate for drupal to understand it?

Comment: @rishariss DrupalAnswers is focusing on Drupal-related code (drupal_http_request being one of them) so I just wanted to explain why this question suits StackOverflow but not DrupalAnswers. Hope you'll find the answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright i made it work so that it reports the server accurately. Im still not exactly sure what was wrong but well, its way more simple and if anyone else wants to know how to connect drupal 7 with Lineage 2 dedicated server to check the status, here's the code:

```
<div class="serverstatus">  
<?php
$server = "server ip";
$portg = "game server port";
$portl = "login server port";
$timeout = "1";

$game = @fsockopen("$server", $portg, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
$login = @fsockopen("$server", $portl, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);

    echo "Login Server: ";
    echo $login ? "<font color=\"green\">OnLine</font>" : "<font color=\"red\">Off line</font>";
    echo "<br>Game Server: ";
    echo $game ? "<font color=\"green\">OnLine</font>" : "<font color=\"red\">Off line</font>";
?>
</div>
```

Thanks for all the answers, regards.